# Is there any way to hide SSRS report paramteres using expressions?

Tags: reporting-services, formula, ssrs-2012

I have created one report in SSRS-2012. I need to show/hide(not inactive) one parameter based on one formula. Is it possible. I am using Visual studio 2010 for my front-end development and report viewer control for showing the report.

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to dinamically hide parameters in SSRS. Depending on your requeriments you may have two ways to handle this issue.

Create one subreport for all parameters and another subreport that does not include the parameter you want to hide, then show dinamically the subreport to the user based on your expression.

Other option is have another parameter set as `internal`. And conditionally populate that parameter based on your expression. If your condition yields true, populate the parameter with the user selection, otherwise use a default value or populate it to null. At presentation level your parameter keeps appearing but the user selection will take effect only based on your expression.

I think the second option is easier, let me know if you need further help.